# How to make a custom number formatting for trillions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

I found this online which formats thousands, millions, and billions

```
[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"
```

[number format sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDxVx.png)

how would you format it so it's by millions, billions, and trillions

Link to [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RKtJnA8bsN5iivK-3QXLgEL0uMJPr6KsCVbU1Ho8-bM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this "internal" formatting is by default able to work with only 3 types of numbers:

- positive (1, 2, 5, 10, ...)
- zero (0)
- negative (-3, -9, -7, ...)

this can be somehow tweaked to show custom formatting like K, B, M but you always got only 3 slots you can use, meaning that you can't have trillions as the 4th type/slot

---

```
[<999950000]0.0,"M";[<999950000000]0.0,,"B";0.0,,,"T"
```

[image]

Comment: ohhh okay how would you format is so that its only M, B, T instead